# Google analytics events tracking stopped working

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm running a site that has event tracking on various adverts on the index.htm page. This tracking had been working fine but for some reason it's now stopped! The standard analytics info is still being registered (page views etc.). I'm using exactly the same code on other pages within the site and they're working without any problems.  I'm pulling my hair it over this one!!

Any ideas???

Here's an example of my tracking code (from within an anchor link):

```
onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Adverts', 'Home Page', 'AXT');"
```

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your interest and pointing me in the right direction Sudar :)

I've managed to get to the bottom of it and you were right - it was the Google Analytics upgrade that has caused the problems. Google have upgraded me without advising so the Event tracking stopped working.

I've grabbed the new analytics code and have changed all the event tracking code for every advert.

This site is quite useful for generating the Event tracking code: http://www.seoweather.com/google-analytics-event-tracking-code-generator/

Answer (score 0):

The way you track custom variables and events changed in Universal tracking. Did you recently upgrade your tracking code to Universal tracking (analytics.js)?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm wondering if Google has automatically upgraded it without my knowledge because apparently that can happen. The strange thing is that these events ARE being tracked on some web pages and not others. Any idea why that should be? (they all have exactly the same code in them by the way)

Comment: Select the "view page code" option in your browser and see if you are using ga.js or analytics.js and post it here.